# Get HTML Source after JavaScript manipulations

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

How do i get the full! HTML source of a web page, after it has run some JavaScript code which has made manipulations to the HTML source.

I'm using the WebbrowserControl of VB.Net, i'd like to create an extra function of my custom webbrowsercontrol which receives the full HTML source.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the JS code that is running triggered by the user, or is it run when the page is loaded?

Comment: The js runs when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is going to be finding a way to notify the control about whether the JS is done running. You might be able to do that by having the JS set a form element' value (isJSComplete) when it has completed and polling with the web browser control.

**Use the following code to check a form value to see if it is ready**

```
MyBrowserControl.document.getElementById('isJSComplete');
```

**Use the following code to pull the HTML from the page.**

```
MyBrowserControl.Document.documentElement.OuterHTML
```

Better yet, here is an [article](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/27/1334.aspx) showing how to wire up JS events to be handled by the WebBrowser control. You could just fire an event when the JS is done and have your code trap that event and then pull the HTML using the above approach.

Comment: This is what i'm looking for.
I'm going to test it out this evening, thanks in advance!