# Get text value from especific class in web site

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it is possible to go to a site and retrieve the text of an element

i think something like

```
a = page("www.site.com")
b = a.getElementByClass("name")
console.log(b.text)
```

this is possible?

Comment: I think this is similar to your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860650/how-to-get-value-from-external-website-while-the-value-is-set-by-javascript-in-t?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called the innerText property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 0):

That depends,

If you want to get the `innerText` of the elements, then

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("YourClassName");
for(let i=0;i<elements.length; i++){
  /*doSOmething*/
   console.log(elements[i].innerText);
}
```

---

Many elements may have `same className`. So, if you want to access some specific Element, then you should either know the `index of the element` or you need to use `id` for the element.

```
let element = document.getElementById("YourElementId");
  /*doSOmething*/
console.log(element.innerText);
```